# How to get 2 using a standard scientific calculator without pressing the number buttons 0 to 9 and the buttons $+-\times\div$?

Tags: logarithms, calculator

I was challenged by a friend to get a number 2 by using a standard scientific calculator but without pressing the number buttons 0 to 9 and the buttons $+-\times\div$. I could get 1 from $\ln e=1$. But I cannot get 2?

Thanks for the helps!

Comment: $e\to e^2\to\ln(e^2)=2$. That is, press `e` `^2` `ln`.

Comment: Can you press the squared key?

Comment: But you are pressing the 2 button ?

Comment: @user71346 On the scientific calculators I've seen, the squaring button is different from the 2 button.

Comment: @user71346 It obviously depends. If you search _scientific calculator_ on Google, it helpfully gives you one, but with no squared key. But if you look at Google Images, most of the calculators there _do_ have one. (Note: The Google calculator works more like a graphing calculator. In fact, you can type in $\ln(ee)$ in it, which also gives 2.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln(ee)$, which most calculators will treat as multiplication.

Comment: You're probably thinking of a graphing calculator. On a scientific calculator, you can't write out entire equations. (It's literally a normal calculator with more buttons.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw Oh...I was thinking along the lines of a TI-30X

Comment: I just realized, though - If you search _scientific calculator_ on Google, it gives you one like you're thinking of. It has no squaring key, but you _can_ type $\ln(ee)$ on it. (But, when you look at Google images, it shows you photos of the type that I had in mind - in which case you can do `e` `^2` `ln`.)

Comment: I got to it by e -> x^2 (single key) -> log using the calculator here https://math.tools/scientific-calculator.